# A compact operator on a non-separable Hilbert space has $0$ in its point spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $H$ is a non-separable Hilbert space and $T:H \to H$ be compact , then show that $0 \in \sigma_{p}(T)$.

I have no idea about working on a non-separable Hilbert space. It is obvious that it won't have a countable orthonormal basis. Apart from that I don't know anything about non-separble Hilbert Space. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Use (and prove, if unfamiliar) the fact that the range of a compact operator is always separable.

Comment: I know this fact. But then you can say that T is not onto. Then 0  cannot be in the resolvent. Hence 0 is  in the spectrum. But what I need to prove is that 0 is an eigen value, that is T is not one-one.. But can we easily conclude that T is not one-one?

Comment: Have you looked at $S=T^*T$, which is selfadjoint and compact?

Comment: @DisintegrationByParts Is it correct? If wrong kindly clarify. Since $T^*T$ is compact $0\in \sigma(T^*T)$. Moreover $\exists x_n\in S_H$ such that $lim_{n\to infty}<T^*Tx_n,x_n>=0$ i.e, $||Tx_n||\to 0$. Hence $Tx_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Since $T$ is compact $\exists  y\in S_H$ such that $Ty=0$. Hence $T$ is not injective. Then we can get the conclusion.

Comment: @happy how do you get sequence $X_{n}$ such that $\langle T^{*}T(x_{n}), x_{n} \rangle $ tend to 0 as n tends to infinity.

Comment: Apply the spectral theorem for $S = \sum_n \lambda_n P_n$ where $\lambda_n \ne 0$ and $P_n$ is the orthogonal projections onto the eigenspace with eigenvalue $\lambda_n \ne 0$. The range of $S$ is separable. So $\mathcal{R}(S)^{\perp} \ne 0$, which is $\mathcal{N}(S)$. And $\mathcal{N}(S)=\mathcal{N}(T^*T)=\mathcal{N}(T)$.

Comment: If $\alpha \in \sigma(T)$ where $T$ is a bounded linear operator on Hilbert space then $\exists x_n\in S_H$ such that $lim_{\infty}<Tx_n,x_n>=\alpha$. Because when $\alpha$ is in approximate point spectrum then using definition of approximate point spectrum and when $\alpha$ is not in approximate point spectrum then using the fact $\overline{\alpha}$ is eigen value of $T^*$. But I am not sure about the existence of $y$!

Answer (score 8):

The point is to show that $\ker T\ne\{0\}$.

Assume first that $T$ is selfadjoint. 
Since $T$ is compact, every nonzero element of the spectrum is an eigenvalue with finite multiplicity, and there are at most countably many nonzero eigenvalues. That is, $$ T=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_kP_k,$$ where $\{P_j\}$ are pairwise orthogonal finite-rank projections.

As $Tx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_kP_kx$, we deduce that the image of $T$ is (at most) countably-dimensional. Now, since 
$$
H=\ker T\oplus \overline{\text{ran}\,T},
$$
it follows that $\ker T$ is nonzero; actually, it has uncountable dimension.

For non-selfadjoint $T$, use the fact that $\ker T=\ker T^*T$.